# #ask #angularJS gulp-ng-annotate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have error at gulp on angularJS, display Error in plugin 'gulp-ng-annotate'
app.js: couldn't process source due to parse error

first, I don't know what gulp-ng-annotate function,anybody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gulp-ng-annotate is an automated build task, it will catch most dependencies, but it sometimes requires hints using the /* @ngInject */ syntax.

To resolve error issue, update  "gulp-ng-annotate": "~0.3.6" to "gulp-ng-annotate": "^0.5.2", 
 run:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-ng-annotate
```

or

```
sudo npm install --save-dev gulp-ng-annotate
```

After run "npm update"

```
npm update
```