# error with gulp-ng-annoate, couldn't process source due to parse error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, mean-stack

I am getting trouble with error that is generated with gulp-ng-annoate.

Error message is

> Error: app.js: error: couldn't process source due to parse error

I've found the other thread which seems to have same problem with me but that answer does not work for me.
[the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825572/ask-angularjs-gulp-ng-annotate)

Here is my gulp file and the files that I am trying to execute the tasks.

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var concat = require('gulp-concat')
//var uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate')

gulp.task('js', function(){
    gulp.src(['ng/module.js', 'ng/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())
        //.pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets'))
})
```

and files that I am trying to concat/ngAnnotate

### module.js

```
angular.module('app', [])
```

### posts.ctrl.js

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('PostCtrl', function($scope, PostsSvc){
    $scope.addPost = function(){
        if ($scope.postBody){
            PostsSvc.create({
                username: 'dickeyxxx',
                body: $scope.postBody
            }).success(function(post){
                $scope.posts.unshift(post)
                $scope.postBody = null
            })
        }
    }

    PostsSvc.fetch().success(function(posts){
        $scope.posts = posts
    })
})
```

### posts.svc.js

```
angular.module('app')
.service('PostsSvc', ['$http', function ($http){
    this.fetch = function(){
        return $http.get('/api/posts')
    }
    this.create = function(post){
        return $http.post('/api/posts', post)
    }
}])
```

What could have gone wrong..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong is that you put a `.` instead a `,` to separate object.

Also, don't forget the `;` to end your line.

Comment: I am not sure which file's which line you are referring to for "put a . instead a , to separate object"? And I would assume that JS would allow not putting ; to end of line unless it is required?

Comment: the problem is here : `PostsSvc.create({ username: 'dickeyxxx'. body: $scope.postBody})`. Adding `; `is the cleanest way to write JS, is you came to compress your code in 1 line, you will have some problems by omitting `;`