# Error MSB3073: The command "grunt dist" exited with code 3 in visual studio 2017

Tags: node.js, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, gruntjs, publish

I am getting issue while publishing the project.

The below output generated while publishing

```
VWT.AIA.WebAPI -> D:\Dev\V2-master\app\src\WebAPI\bin\Release\net452\win7-x86\WebAPI.exe
grunt dist
[4mRunning "clean:dist" (clean) task[24m
[32m>> [39m1 path cleaned.

[4mRunning "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task[24m
Configuration changed for [36mconcat[39m, [36muglify[39m, [36mcssmin[39m

[4mRunning "ngtemplates:dist" (ngtemplates) task[24m
File [36m./target/usemin-temp/template.js[39m created.
Added [36m./target/usemin-temp/template.js[39m to [33m<!-- build:js scripts/aia.min.js -->[39m

[4mRunning "concat:generated" (concat) task[24m

[4mRunning "ngAnnotate:dist" (ngAnnotate) task[24m
Generating "target/usemin-temp/concat/scripts/aia.min.js" from: "target/usemin-temp/concat/scripts/aia.min.js"...[31mERROR[39m
[31m>> [39merror: couldn't process source due to parse error
[31m>> [39mUnexpected token (3713:132)
[33mWarning: Task "ngAnnotate:dist" failed. Use --force to continue.[39m

[31mAborted due to warnings.[39m
D:\Dev\master\app\src\WebAPI\WebAPI.csproj(108,5): Error MSB3073: The command "grunt dist" exited with code 3.
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think** the issue is that the command on the pre-build event or post-build event of the **WebAPI** project is wrong.

Right-click on your **WebApi** project-->**Properties**-->**Build Event** and the command `grunt dist` are written there.

**I am afraid** that the js files of your project has something wrong. And according to the error message, the issue is here:

```
target/usemin-temp/concat/scripts/aia.min.js
```

And you can try the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

**1)** install the [latest nodejs version 14.14.0](https://nodejs.org/en/).

**2)** run VS as **Administrator**

**3)** run this command:

```
npm uninstall grunt-ng-annotate --save-dev

npm install grunt-ng-annotate@0.10.0 --save-dev
```

**4)** check on that js file very carefully and make sure that there are no grammatical errors on that file. There is [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816958/error-with-gulp-ng-annoate-couldnt-process-source-due-to-parse-error).

**Besides**, check  on your all html files, maybe there are some unclosed tags or extra tags on html files.

**In addition**, if it does not work, I suggest you could share your js file and your `packages.json` with us to locate the problem further.